# Repeating iCal Events in AppleScript

Tags: date, applescript, icalendar, repeat

How do I get all of the dates on which a repeating iCal event occurs in AppleScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting this info from ical is tough using applescript. However there is a command line tool you can use. And of course since it's a command line tool you can automate the tool using applescript. See [here](http://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/).

Comment: How do I use this to get the repeat dates?